# Javascript var inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie with javascript and I want to understand why this isn't working:

```
var firstName = $("#firstName").val();

$("#account").on('submit', function() {
     console.log(firstName); // Empty value
});
```

jsfiddle: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/76gezoos/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the initial value of input and storing it in a string variable. Instead store the jQuery object reference in the variable and get value whenever you want.

```
var firstName = $("#firstName");

$("#account").on('submit', function() {
  console.log(firstName.val());
});
```

```js
var firstName = $("#firstName");

$("#account").on('submit', function() {
  console.log(firstName.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="account" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="firstName">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah! That's it. Worked exactly as I need (use outside function(){});. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

The way your code is written, it grabs the value of the firstname field when the page is first loaded and stores that in the variable `firstName`.  Then, sometime later it outputs that stored value to the console.  If you want the current value of that field, you have to fetch the current value at the time you output it like this:

```
$("#account").on('submit', function() {
     var firstName = $("#firstName").val();   // get current value
     console.log(firstName); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's always holding the default value. You need to grab the value upon submission of form

```
var firstNameDefault = $("#firstName");

$("#account").on('submit', function() {
    var firstNameAfterClick = $("#firstName");
    console.log(firstName.val()); // Empty value
    console.log(firstNameAfterClick.val()); // Should display value of #firstName after form is submitted
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstName = $("#firstName").val(); // move this line from here to inside the function

$("#account").on('submit', function() {
     var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
     console.log(firstName); // Empty value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, get the value on input on submission, not before it.

```
$("#account").on('submit', function() {
     var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
     console.log(firstName); // non-empty value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working actually. its just that the variable `username` is not getting the latest value from `$("#firstName")`

Here is a sample of what is happening :

```
var firstName = $("#firstName").val(); // this line says that get the value of #firstName
```

For example `#firstName` is a textbox, this will probably have an empty value since you haven't assigned any value on it. Unless you assign any value on it, the first line will always have an empty data.

```
$("#account").on('submit', function() {
     console.log(firstName); // Empty value
});
```

This line here when `#account` is submitted, print whats inside `firstName` in the console. But you got the previous value which is empty because you retrieved the **very first** value of `#firstName`. 
If you want to print the current or latest value of `#firstName`, then take a look at the answer of others.
I just explained what really happened in you code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a default value in `#firstName` you want to see the default value without any change in the browser console. For submission of the form the page is refreshing so you can not see the console value. so just add one more line `return false;` to see the in the console.

```
<script>
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();

    $("#account").on('submit', function() {
        console.log(firstName); 
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

*** and don't forget to remove `return false;` after completion of your debugging otherwise form will not submit to the server.